# Prevent MySQL from using temporary table when selecting from date ranges

Tags: mysql

I am trying to prevent mysql from creating a temporary table in this query

```
SELECT `vendor_id`,SUM(`qty`) AS `qty`
FROM   `inventory_transactions` 

WHERE `inventory_transactions`.`date`
    BETWEEN '2018-10-21 00:00:00' AND '2018-10-22 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY `vendor_id`
```

I've tried re-arranging the indexes, using `SELECT DISTINCT`, `MIN(vendor_id)`,`MAX(vendor_id)`, adding a `COUNT(*)` Column in an attempt to see if it would use the index to sort.

I've had `ix(date,type,vendor_id)` in every variation as well as individual indexes.

I just can't seem to figure out why mysql keeps trying to sort from a temporary table, the only way it doesn't use a temp table is if i group by the `date` column, which is not what I want.

Anyone have any insight as to how to fix it?

**Table Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE `transactions` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `vendor_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `type` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `unit_cost` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
 `qty` decimal(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
 `location_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `date` timestamp NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `location_id` (`location_id`),
 KEY `type` (`type`),
 KEY `vendor_id` (`vendor_id`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `date` (`date`,`vendor_id`,`type`) USING BTREE,
 CONSTRAINT `transactions_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`location_id`) REFERENCES `locations` (`id`),
 CONSTRAINT `transactions_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`vendor_id`) REFERENCES `vendors` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**EXPLAIN**

```
+----+-------------+------------------------+------------+-------+----------------------+------------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                  | partitions | type  | possible_keys        | key        | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                                                     |
+----+-------------+------------------------+------------+-------+----------------------+------------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | inventory_transactions | NULL       | range | vendor_id,date       | date       | 4       | NULL | 1196 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+------------------------+------------+-------+----------------------+------------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Have you tried an index on `(vendor_id, date)`?

Comment: Yeah, tried `(vendor_id,date)` `(date,vendor_id)` even `(type,vendor_id)`

Comment: Not sure why you would try that last one, since the query never uses `type`.

Comment: Have you tried using the `FORCE INDEX` clause?

Comment: @Barmar Haven't tried force index yet, and i tried `type`,`vendor_id` because i was originally filtering `type` in the where clause. not relevant in this scenario :P

Comment: It might simply be that the cardinality of the index isn't adequate for it think that using the index will be better.

Comment: It's using the index `date (date,vendor_id,type) USING BTREE` automatically, i tried forcing it to use other indexes but it reverts to full table scan on most of them. The temporary table is only created when i use the `GROUP BY` clause, if i used `GROUP BY date` then it would not create a temp table, but would still use `filesort`.

Comment: Based on manual (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-optimization.html) MySQL cannot optimize such group by. You can try index (date, vendor_id, qty) so MySQL will use index only without lookups to data. However, it would still use temporary.